# Why PHP couldn't get $_POST data from Js FormData fetch?

Tags: php, fetch-api, form-data

I want to send JSON data (in this case is client timestamp) to my server. However, my code seem doesn't work as I expect.

My idea is using fetch to send FormData (which contain an input has JSON as value) to the PHP. At the server side, PHP will take care the form with `$_POST` and return JSON string to me.

I'm using a free host service, which has PHP 7.0, for testing stuff.

All of the code below is in the same file (404.php):

```
var now = new Date();

var pkg = JSON.stringify({
    ts: now.getTime(),
    tz: now.getTimezoneOffset() / -60
})

var form = new FormData();
form.set('json', pkg);

console.log(form.has('json')) // true
console.log(form.values().next()) // return and obj contain JSON string

fetch('/404.php', {
    method: 'POST',
    body: form
});
```

```php
$json = null;
if(isset($_POST['json'])) $json = json_decode($_POST['json']);

var_dump($_POST); //Result: array(0) { }
```

As you can see, the output of var_dump is an empty array. But what I expect to see is an output with a JSON string.

I've tried another way, which is this one [fetch-api-json-php](https://codepen.io/dericksozo/post/fetch-api-json-php), but it also no use. All the resource I found on the Internet usually about the classic AJAX, not fetch API. And most of them are only for client side, there isn't much I could find for PHP/server side.

Comment: What does $_POST on the PHP side contain? Have you var_dump'd the content of $_POST?

Comment: Yes, it returns empty array.

Comment: Sorry. you posted that. So it's not PHP side but JS side. I assume that you need to send `form.values()`instead of `form` inside your `fetch()`. To be sure that the right data is sent check in the network tab in your developer console that the right data is transfered to the script. If nothing is sent in the body of the request PHP has nothung to work with

Comment: You could also simplify things and replace `body: form.values()` with `body : {"json" : PKG} ` and skip all the form business.

Comment: I don't think so, the fetch code I use is the common one on the Internet. But of course, everything's worth to try. However, nothing changes...

Comment: So what does your browser actually  send?

Comment: ‍♂️ IIRC `form` is a reserved name in the global scope. Rename the variable for a test and see what happens.

Comment: How do I track it? The network tab of Firefox doesn't do the job

Comment: You JS file located in the same folder where PHP file for the post request?

Becuase I ran your code in my localhost, I just change the POST request URl in fetch() method and its working just fine.

Comment: I've just changed from `form` to `formx` but it still doesn't work. I also try to test on Chrome but it's got the same result.

Comment: The network tab of firefox devtools contains all requests that are sent. Unless you have set a filter. See f. e. https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Tools/Network_Monitor

Comment: All of the code about are in the same file which is `404.php`. And I run this file on and actual host, not local one. (I don't know if I should add the link to here, I don't really believe in free host so it might look like spam)

Comment: @heiglandreas Do you think this could be server's fault? A [screenshot](https://imgur.com/ugKSPiF) that I capture from Chrome tab tells it get `error 500` why sending data.

Comment: when I interpret your screenshot from the Chrome DevTools (not Firefox DevTools) correctly you are sending the complete string as POST parameter to the script. That is a) not valid JSON and b) not valid POST-data as it's not key/value pairs. But as you already got a working answer that's fine.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Can you try to run this code in your local machine?

Make a file name 55788817.php and paste this code and run.

```
  <?php
  if (isset($_POST) && !empty($_POST)) {
    $json = null;
    if(isset($_POST['json'])) $json = json_decode($_POST['json']);

    var_dump($_POST); //Result: array(1) { ["json"]=> string(29) "{"ts":1555915560755,"tz":5.5}" }
    exit;
  }
  ?>
  <!DOCTYPE html>
  <html>
  <head>
    <title></title>
  </head>
  <body>
    <button type="button" id="registerButton">Click Me!</button>
    <script>
      var now = new Date();

      var pkg = JSON.stringify({
          ts: now.getTime(),
          tz: now.getTimezoneOffset() / -60
      })

      var form = new FormData();
      form.append('json', pkg);

      console.log(form.has('json')) // true
      console.log(form.values().next()) // return and obj contain JSON string
      fetch('./55788817.php', {
          method: 'POST',
          body: form
      });
    </script>
  </body>
  </html>
```

Comment: Do I have to run it on local host? Because I'm not using my pc (borrowing one, in fact) so I can not set up a localhost. But I has added your script to my shared-host and tried. What should I expect after click the button because it doesn't seem like return anything.

Comment: Check in Chrome > inspect > network tab and see the response for the above file.

Comment: Here is the result: [screenshot](https://imgur.com/ugKSPiF). I'm getting start to think this is the server's fault.

Comment: Hmm, have you check the request URL in fetch method? is correct path?

If you think my answer help please mark this answer as Useful, thanks.

Comment: it's on the same file so it can be wrong url. Ok, will mark this answer for now.

Answer (score 0):

This worked for me:

```
<!doctype html>
<html>
<head>
<meta charset="UTF-8">
<script>
    var pkg = '{"test":"data"}';
    var formData = new FormData();
    formData.set('json', pkg);

    fetch('./404.php', {
      method: 'POST',
      body: formData
    });
</script>
</head>
<body>

</body>
</html>
```

PHP:

```
<?php
$json = null;
if(isset($_POST['json'])) 
    $json = json_decode($_POST['json']);

var_dump($_POST, $json); 

// Result: array(1) { ["json"]=> string(15) "{"test":"data"}" } object(stdClass)#1 (1) { ["test"]=> string(4) "data" } 

?>
```

Comment: It doesn't work for me. Even if I set `pkg` a pure string value like you do. It still return a `null` value for `$json`.

Answer (score 0):

Here a generic way to achieve this

HTML

```
<form name="myform" action="serverScriptOrFile.json" method="post">
    <input name="xxx"/>
</form>
```

Javascript

```
document.querySelector("form[name='myform']")?.addEventListener('submit', (e) => {
    e.preventDefault()
    fetch(e.target.action, {
        method: e.target.method,
        body: new FormData(e.target)
    })
    .then(response => response.json())
    .then(json => {
        console.log(json)
    })
})
```